# How to change \x in a function declaration and still plot it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, function

I can plot the following MWE

```tex
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{physics}

\pgfplotsset{
  nice_axis/.style={
    xlabel={$f \cdot T_c$},
    ylabel={$10 \cdot \log_{10}\left( \abs{P_\sqcap \left( T_c \cdot f \right)}^{2} \right)$},
    grid=both,
    axis lines=box,
    domain=-10:10,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nice_axis,
    declare function={
    P_sqr(\x) = sin(pi*\x)/(pi*\x);
  },
  ]
    \addplot[black, thick, mark=none] {10*log10(abs(P_sqr(\x)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, if a change `\x` by something else, say, `\fTc`, it doesn't compile properly. I get the following error:

> ./PSD_rect_pulse.tex:26: Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '10*log10(abs(P_sqr()))').

I suppose `\x` has a special meaning in \addplot will try to plot it. If so, is it to change this behavior in order to `\x` by something else and still plot it?

Comment: Likely add `variable=fTc` to option-list of `axis` and use `P_sqr(fTc)` in `\addplot` argumemt. ( notice, both without the backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x` is the default name for the variable, but you can use whatever you want, provided you tell it to `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
  nice_axis/.style={
    xlabel={$f \cdot T_c$},
    ylabel={$10 \cdot \log_{10}(|P_\sqcap ( T_c \cdot f )|^{2})$},
    grid=both,
    axis lines=box,
    domain=-10:10,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nice_axis,
    declare function={
    P_sqr(\x) = sin(pi*\x)/(pi*\x);
  },
  ]
    \addplot[variable=\pippo,black, thick, mark=none] {10*log10(abs(P_sqr(\pippo)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]